# how to make position:absolute (vertical align bottom) element overflow:scroll?

Tags: html, css

I recently work on an project that has some kind of structure like:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="children">
       sample text
   </div>
</div>
```

the .parent got a fixed height like 700px, and the .children is supposed to be vertical align at bottom of the parent. So I set the parent as `position:relative; height:700px` and the children as `position:absolute; bottom:0;`, the problem is that what should I do if the "sample text" is too long that it extends out of the parent? we want to be able to scroll so that we dont miss the text. but set the .parent `overflow:scroll` will not work because of the position things.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something and found that set some attributes to .children like

```
.children{
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

could accomplish this objective. I don't know if anyone got the same problem, so I just share at this question. If anyone got better ideas, please share with us, thank you.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Making the classes look like this

```
.parent {
    position:relative;
    height:700px;
}
.children {
    overflow:scroll;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0%;
}
```

Seems to work in the [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/6bG7j/). The thing with the bottom:0 or 0px is not working and I don't know why exactly.

Cheers.